# Select users which have at least one successful and one failed payment per month in PostgresQl

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

How can I select users from this kind of table that have at least one successful and one failed payment per month?
For example if the user has payments in March, April and May and in may there was only ten successful payments we don't want to show that user but if the user has had payments for as long as 10 months an in each month there are failed(false) and successful(true) payments, we want to show that user....

In this case we would only show users with user id 1 and 3

for now my query looks like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('month', paydate)as uniquemonth
     , success
     ,user_id 
FROM payments order by user_id,uniquemonth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the distinct months with failed and successful payments:

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id
having count(*) filter (where success) = count(*)  and
       count(*) filter (where not success) = count(*);
```

You seem to have only one or two records per month.  If you have more and the first column were really not the first of the month, you could use `count(distinct)`:

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id
having count(distinct date_trunc('month', uniquemonth)) filter (where success) = count(distinct date_trunc('month', uniquemonth)) and
       count(distinct date_trunc('month', uniquemonth)) filter (where not success) = count(distinct date_trunc('month', uniquemonth))
```

Comment: Thank a lot but this query seems to show the user with id 2 which has payments in two distinct months 2001-11-01(true) and 2012-11-01 (false) but it should show only if it has one true and one false value in each month e.g. 2001-11-01 (true, false) ,  2012-11-01 (true, false )... just like user one has two payments in 8th month one true and other false

Comment: @gurbajani . . . Good catch.  I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way:

```
select 
  to_char(uniquemonth, 'YYYY-MM')
  , users
from tablename
group by to_char(uniquemonth, 'YYYY-MM'), users
having count(*) filter (where success) > 1
   and count(*) filter (where not success) > 1;
```

Comment: It worked thanks a million! btw does "filter" belong to SQL or only Postgres? could not find it in SQL documentation...

Comment: you are welcome,its a PostgreSQL specific command

Comment: @gurbajani . . . Are you just looking for a single month with a successful and unsuccessful payment?  I interpreted the question as requiring that every month ("per month" implies for all months, not just one).

Answer (score 1):

Use `MIN()` and `MAX()` window functions to get the min and max values of `success` for each user/month and then use aggregation:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         MIN(success::int) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, to_char(paydate, 'YYYY-MM')) min_success,
         MAX(success::int) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, to_char(paydate, 'YYYY-MM')) max_success 
  FROM payments
) t
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING MAX(min_success) = 0 AND MIN(max_success) = 1
```

Comment: I got help already, thanks for the support, much appreciated !